# Accessing tomcat server log from page(front-end)

Tags: java, tomcat

Is there a way you could access tomcat server log from page? If there are some methods, or an implementation that could do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PSI Probe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) can list your Tomcat log files and show their contents. You could take the same approach and just list and display the files in your log directory from your web app.

Comment: Seems interesting...I'll have a look.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of options - logs are just plain text files somewhere n your filesystem, so you can configure a context allowing access to them. But beware that access to logs shall be restricted, as they can (and certainly do) contain sensitive infroamtion

Comment: Yeah, I know I could treat the log just as a ordinary file in my system, but what if the path changes, the server location changes to another computer...I want something sure, something independent from the Tomcat location!

Comment: if server location changes you will have to reconfigure your server anyway. Ofcourse, this is possible to store log messages not in file system but in some NoSQL-database for realtime analyzis (and this is done by big installations )  -  but I doubt such overkill is justified in your case